# What are those decorative things called?

Tags: single-word-requests

[image]

I painted this some years ago, and I *still* don't know what they're called. The vases, or bowls, or whatever they are, on top of the two pillars pretending to support the porch? They're shaped like spheres sometimes. What's the term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term is "finial" which is a noun and is defined in the MW as a crowning ornament.

Comment: Here's [some suitable images](http://www.chilstone.com/Section.php?Section=Finials) I was going to use in my answer. The specific shape of "vase or bowl" is generally an **urn** (also illustrated at that site).

Comment: 'Finials' usually restricted to solid / enclosed ornaments; 'urns' if open.